# Add date format constraint to varchar attribut

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I'm trying to create this table below in oracle but the i want to add a constraint to datexp (date format 'MM/YYYY') attribute but sadly none of my attempt worked correctly:

```
create table carte
(
    idcarte char(5) primary key,
    typec varchar(20) 
        check(typec in ('E-dinars smart', 'E-dinars universel', 'visa electron', 'visa international', 'mastercard international')),
    datexp varchar(9) ,
    numerocarte number(20),
    signaturecvv2 number(3)
);
```

I tried:

```
datexp varchar(9) check(to_date(datexp, 'MM/YYYY')),

datexp varchar(9) check(date_exp = to_date(datexp, 'MM/YYYY')),
```

Comment: **DO NOT** try to enforce a proper "date format" in your varchar column - instead, use the **appropriate date or date&time datatype** directly - no need to fiddle around with "date formatting" at all, if you store them correctly from the beginning!

Answer (score 4):

From my point of view, that would be **terribly wrong**. Never, EVER store dates as strings. **NEVER**. It is prone to errors, and you shouldn't waste your time on figuring out *how* to create constraints to prevent users from entering invalid dates - let database handle that. How? Simply by setting the `DATE` datatype for that column.

Besides, I'd suggest you to create referential integrity constraint for `carte types`:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE carte_type
  2  (
  3     typec   NUMBER CONSTRAINT pk_cartyp PRIMARY KEY,
  4     name    VARCHAR2 (50) NOT NULL
  5  );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE carte
  2  (
  3     idcarte         CHAR (5) PRIMARY KEY,
  4     typec           NUMBER CONSTRAINT fk_cart_typ REFERENCES carte_type (typec),
  5     datexp          DATE,
  6     numerocarte     NUMBER (20),
  7     signaturecvv2   NUMBER (3)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

If you're worried about date format (`mm/yyyy`), don't worry about that - enter *any* date that belongs to that month/year, and then - when presenting that info to end users - apply desired format mask to `to_char` function, e.g.

```
select to_char(datexp, 'mm/yyyy') as datexp
from ...
```

It doesn't really matter whether you'll enter e.g. 08/12/2021 (dd/mm/yyyy) or 23/12/2021 - both of them are in 12/2021.

Or, if you're using GUI tool (or report builder), it already offers format mask property so - use it.

Answer (score 2):

You should store date values as a `DATE` and can use a check constraint to restrict it to values at the start of the month. You could even add a virtual column to generate `DATEXP` in the required format:

```sql
CREATE TABLE carte(
  idcarte       VARCHAR2(5)
                CONSTRAINT carte__idcarte__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  typec         VARCHAR2(20)
                CONSTRAINT carte__typec__chk CHECK(
                  typec in(
                    'E-dinars smart',
                    'E-dinars universel',
                    'visa electron',
                    'visa international',
                    'mastercard international'
                  )
                ),
  datexp        DATE
                CONSTRAINT carte__datexp__chk CHECK(datexp = TRUNC(datexp, 'MM')),
  formatted_datexp
                VARCHAR2(7)
                GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(datexp, 'MM/YYYY')),
  numerocarte   NUMBER(20),
  signaturecvv2 NUMBER(3)
);
```

---

However, if you have a valid business reason to store it as a string (you probably don't, even if you think you do), from Oracle 12 you could try to convert to a date and use `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` in the check constraint with an exact format model:

```sql
CREATE TABLE carte(
  idcarte       VARCHAR2(5)
                CONSTRAINT carte__idcarte__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  typec         VARCHAR2(20)
                CONSTRAINT carte__typec__chk CHECK(
                  typec in(
                    'E-dinars smart',
                    'E-dinars universel',
                    'visa electron',
                    'visa international',
                    'mastercard international'
                  )
                ),
  datexp        VARCHAR2(7)
                CONSTRAINT carte__datexp__chk CHECK(
                  TO_DATE(datexp DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR, 'FXMM/YYYY')
                    IS NOT NULL
                ),
  numerocarte   NUMBER(20),
  signaturecvv2 NUMBER(3)
);
```

*(Note: In earlier versions, you can drop the `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR` and the constraint will still be checked but it will fail with an exception relating to parsing the date rather than a more descriptive error from the constraint failing.)*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6dc7a753b4b533f5ec3ac77b245da3eb)*

Comment: datexp        DATE
                CONSTRAINT carte__datexp__chk CHECK(datexp = TRUNC(datexp, 'MM')),
i tried this solution but when i want to insert :
insert into paiement values('N0001','CO001','jan-2021','CA001','valide');
or
insert into paiement values('N0001','CO001','01/2021','CA001','valide');
i get this error ((ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01843: not a valid month))

Comment: @MedOussemaZaier Neither of those are dates, they are strings. You need to use `TO_DATE` to convert to a date `INSERT INTO carte (idcarte, typec, datexp, numerocarte, signaturecvv2) values ('N0001','visa electron', TO_DATE('jan-2021', 'mon-yyyy'),1,2);` or use a date literal `INSERT INTO carte (idcarte, typec, datexp, numerocarte, signaturecvv2) values ('N0002','visa electron', DATE '2021-01-01', 1, 2);`.